# How to get back lost data from a dropped table whose backup was not present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with few tables. Accidentally, I dropped one of the table from the database and I have tried all the tools that I can google but almost all need a backup file to restore with. Last backup I have is 5 years old and is not of much use.
I tried to use LSN recovery but the log is not showing DROBOBJ . I just want my data from the table I dropped.
I have used this query to get things from the log:

```
SELECT
    [Current LSN],
    [Operation],
    [Context],
    [Transaction ID],
    [Description]
FROM
    fn_dblog (NULL, NULL),
    (SELECT
        [Transaction ID] AS [tid]
    FROM
        fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
    WHERE
        [Transaction Name] LIKE '%DROPOBJ%') [fd]
WHERE
    [Transaction ID] = [fd].[tid];
GO
```

Save Me !

Comment: Short of having backups, there's probably not much you're going to be able to do.  Possible revert the PC the database is on o a previous state if you're creating restore points??  I think you're going to have an uphill battle with this one .. Back up, and back up **OFTEN!**

Comment: If you dropped the table and you didn't have a backup your data is gone...period...there is no recycle bin for data or tables.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed or at least redirected to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) as it's not specifically about programming.

Comment: On the positive side, I suspect you will be more diligent in backing-up your data.

Comment: You don't.  And we can't save you.  Take this as a life lesson to *always* have backups.

Comment: Last backup was **5 *years*?!**  Yeah, no.  I'm sure some very expensive DBA consultants would be capable of recovering some of the data, but barring that it's safe to say that the data is gone.

Comment: That is just for one table . All other tables are intact ! Is there any way my any means this can be reverted or the query for drop can be rollbacked

Comment: @AmishaMehta No, there is no way to revert the data without either having a backup (which you say you don't have) or utilizing a tracking table (which would have needed to be manually set up prior to this).

Comment: See this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44192/how-do-i-rollback-a-dropped-table-using-log and this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38872/how-to-undo-drop-table-statement